# warning: format '%c' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *'

Tags: c, char

I'm trying to print all characters stored in hex array to the screen, one by one, but I get this strange error in line 16. As far as I know, %c should be expecting a char, not an int.
Why I'm getting this error?
Below is my code, thanks.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <limits.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main() 
    {
        char hex[8] = "cf0a441f";
        int hexCounter;
        char *currentHex;

        for(hexCounter=0; hexCounter<strlen(hex); hexCounter++)
        {
            currentHex = &hex[hexCounter];
            printf("%c",currentHex);
        }   
         return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `hex` has to be declared as `char hex[9]`, not `[8]`.  You forgot the null terminator.

Answer (score 8):

You mean

```
printf("%c", *currentHex);
```

In my opinion you can remove the entire idea of `currentHex` since it just adds complexity for no value. Simply do:

```
printf("%c", hex[hexCounter]);
```

The important point is that you're supposed to pass the *value* of the character itself, not it's address which is what you're doing.

Comment: Because you passed a `currentHex` to `printf`, and `currentHex` is a pointer to a `char`.  BTW, it is not an error but a warning.

Comment: @user1166935: The warning is pretty clear - the `%c` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to be of type `int`, but you were passing an argument of type `char *`.

Comment: Just because it's a warning doesn't mean it's non-serious. It just means the code does not violate a compile-time constraint the compiler is required to enforce. In OP's case, passing the wrong type invokes UB, which is very bad.

Answer (score 2):

You have `hex[hexCounter]` as a `char` so when you set

```
currentHex = &hex[hexCounter];
```

you are setting `currentHex` to the address of a `char`, i.e. a `char *`.  As such, in your `printf` you need

```
printf("%c",*currentHex);
```

What you are doing is unnecessary anyway, since you could just do

```
printf("%c",hex[hexCounter]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`currentHex` should be of type `char`, not `char *`.

```
 char currentHex;

 [..]

 currentHex = hex[hexCounter];
 printf("%c",currentHex);
```

If you really want it to be a pointer, dereference it to print:

```
printf("%c",*currentHex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the modified code which runs fine for me -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    char hex[9] = "cf0a441f";
    unsigned int hexCounter; 
    char *currentHex;
    for(hexCounter=0; hexCounter<strlen(hex); hexCounter++)
    {
        currentHex = &hex[hexCounter];
        printf("%c",*currentHex);
    }   
     return 0;
}
```